# How to kill thread spawned using CLONE_THREAD and blocked on a shared resource in kernel space?

Tags: linux, kernel, futex

I have a test case where there are threads spawned using CLONE_THREAD option in clone() .Here if i want to kill a particular thread I suppose we should be using SYS_tgkill in systemcall(). But will the kill actually affect a thread if it is waiting in kernel space(say a futex_wait)?

I tried killing a thread created in the above manner.But when SIGKILL is sent to the same the whole process is getting killed.Am i missing something in using syscall(SYS_tgkill,pid,tid,9) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIGKILL` **always** kills the target **process**. There is no way around this; it's unblockable, unignorable, and uncatchable.

You could try sending another signal (like `SIGUSR1` or `SIGHUP` or `SIGRTMIN`) and having a signal handler installed that calls `pthread_exit` (but note that this function is not async-signal-safe, so you must ensure that the signal handler did not interrupt another async-signal-unsafe function) or use cancellation (`pthread_cancel`) to stop the blocked thread.

This should work for normal blocking operations (like waiting for data from a pipe or socket), but it will not help you if the thread is in an uninterruptable sleep state (like trying to read from a badly scratched CD or failing hard disk).